# Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1} Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I am executing my automation script using appium but found some error. Can you please help me how to solve below error.

```
File f = new File("D:/External Resource");
File aps = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus 5X API 25");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, aps.getAbsolutePath());
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
TouchAction t = new TouchAction(driver);
t.tap(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1. Custom Adapter']").click();
t.press(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']"));
Thread.sleep(3000);
t.release().perform();
driver.findElementByXPath("");
driver.findElementByXPath("android:id/alertTitle").getText();
```

I have using latest version.
1. Selenium Version : Selenium-java-3.6.0
2.. Appium Java Client : java-client-5.0.3

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {ELEMENT=1}
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'PHO147', ip: '192.168.3.147', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
>   Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:509)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:140)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
>       at gesture.testGest(gesture.java:37)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:415)

Comment: Post the line of code for which this is happening

Comment: @TarunLalwani : I have added my code kindly review it.